# c# com javascript pegar src da imagem usando MouseDoubleClick cefsharp

Tags: javascript, c#, html

```html
<html lang="pt-br"> <head><title></title></head><body><img id="1" alt="1" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/imagenspng_logo4.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><img id="2" alt="2" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/peppa-pig-01.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /><img id="3" alt="3" src="http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/peppa-pig-02.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" /></body></html>
```

bom dia amigos, poderia me ajudar a como pegar o link da imagem com javascript ou c# estou fazendo isso

```
  var res14 = await chromeBrowser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByTagName('img')[2].src");
```

porem nesse caso ele so trás o src da imagem 2, porem preciso que quando clicar na imagem 1 ou em qualquer outra imagem ele traga o caminho.
Grato a todos

Comment: Bem vinda ao Stackoverflow, Kelly! Você quer adicionar função a um clique do mouse sobre uma imagem, é isso? Você pode esclarecer o que você quer dizer com "trazer o caminho da imagem"? Por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/216814/edit) sua pergunta e inclua toda informação que você puder a respeito do que você pretende fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Bem simples, basta usar `onclick` no seu **HTML**.

```js
function selectAvatar(el) {
    var imgSrc = el.src;
    window.alert(imgSrc);
}
```

```html
<img onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="https://2gether4good.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/1_2_3.jpg">
<img onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/V/k/w/7/Z/two-green-square-rounded-edge-th.png">
<img onclick="selectAvatar(this)" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/number4/number4_PNG15037.png?i=1">
```

Comment: não sei como faço para isso `function selectAvatar(el) { var imgSrc = el.src; window.alert(imgSrc); }` virar algo parecido com isso pq estou usando c# `var res14 = await chromeBrowser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.getElementsByTa‌​gName('img')[2].src"‌​);`

Comment: certo, más como vou passar isso par o c# ou para o vb.net